# R changing decimals to incorrect scientific notation

Tags: r, excel, formatting, scientific-notation

I'm trying to import data from an excel spreadsheet into R in this format:

| Sample | Test |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0.006 |
| C | 0.235668 |
| D | 0.000004 |
| E | 4 |
| F | >64 |

However when I load it into R using `read_excel` it looks like this:

| Sample | Test |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 6.0000000000000001E-3 |
| C | 0.235668 |
| D | 3.9999999999999998E-6 |
| E | 4 |
| F | >64 |

I've tried formatting it in excel as general or text (can't do numeric because of some symbols) and I've tried `options(scipen=100)` and  `format(test$Test, scientific = FALSE, justified = "none")` and no matter what I it still formats it in this way. WHY???

Comment: Your second code example uses `test$test` but the column name is `Test` with upper-case T.

Comment: I can't replicate this at all (with an xlsx like yours, saved in OpenOffice).  The ">64" in the last column makes the column be read in as character, which makes it read the literal digits (rather than doing the floating-point weirdness you see). Can you post a link to your file?

Comment: Edited "test$Test" for the example in the question but that's clearly not the problem I'm having since I made the test file specifically as a reproducible example (and also to test if it was an issue with my data or still did this with a test file.

Comment: I wonder if OpenOffice vs Excel makes a difference? The file I made was literally just typing these numbers into two columns in Excel

Answer (score 0):

I created an Excel sheet using your data. It seems that the issue is the sixth row where the value for Test = ">64". This means that column `Test` in the resulting data frame is of type character.

However, I only see scientific notation for the value 0.000004, which becomes 4.0E-6, so I suspect that your example data is not exactly what you have in your Excel file.

One solution may be to use `dplyr::mutate` to convert the column to numeric. Assuming the data frame is named `test`:

```
test <- test %>% 
  mutate(Test = as.numeric(gsub(">", "", Test)))
```

If you have symbols other than ">" (you mention "some symbols"), you'll need to modify the `gsub`.

Comment: I had this issue with my actual data so I made an excel file where I typed these exact test numbers into the file and the results showed up as shown in my example. I just don't understand why R would add or subtract very tiny decimals while changing to scientific notation, like why would 0.000004 become 3.9999999999999998E-6 and not 4.0E-6? Straight scientific notation is easier to deal with. The "Some Symbols" I have are just greater than/less than signs and I need these in my data as they're actual values. Interestingly though, this problem went away when I saved it as a .csv file.